# axios return error on status 200

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, axios

I have a problem with axios. Even when request returns with 200 promise is always rejected.

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('email', credentials.email);
params.append('password', credentials.password);
params.append('grant_type', 'email');
params.append('scope', 'read write');
let promise = axios.post('/backend/oauth/token', params, {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  let loginData = response.data;
  let expiredAt;
  expiredAt = new Date;
  expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + loginData.expires_in);
  loginData.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
  store.set('token', loginData);
}, (err) => {
  console.log("LOL");
  console.log(err);
});
```

error function is always called, and err object has status: '200', statusText: 'ok'. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I thought it was the new Date instead of new Date()... remember if you do any error in the success handler (then) it also jumps out to the catch handler... but then maybe this was just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my error, in one of my response interceptors that I forgot about I was rejecting the promise.